# Powershell search and replace part of a string

Tags: powershell, search, replace

I have a file with the following content:

> 1**2**3
>   4**5**6
>   7**8**9
>   XYZ
>   ABC999XXXXXXX

I need to search the file for 3 numeric characters, and replace the first and third character based on user input. If the user inputs character 1 = 0 and character 3 = 9, I need to return.

> 0**2**9
>   0**5**9
>   0**8**9

I'm trying to do this with a simple search and replace, without creating a variable for each character. Also of note, I need to search for the criteria of 3 numbers, discarding the alpha character rows.

Please Note: This is a simplified version of what I need to do. The situation is long with many more fields but I hope that boiling this down will give me something that I can work with. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-replace'^\d(\d)\d$','0${1}9'`

Comment: If the user selects 1=0, you need to turn 4 into 0 and 7 into 0?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of what you have tried? PetSerAl give you the larger part of what you need.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - I think the user input would mean "Make all the first characters 0 and all the third characters 9. At least that is the interpretation that the example supports.

Comment: @EBGreen Oh of course, 1 and 3 meaning the first and third characters; I was mixing up because the first line has 1 and 3 *in* those positions.

Comment: In what ways could the input vary? Can the user set values for any character position, or only the first and third character? Also, do you want to update the original file with the results, or return them separately?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the conditions are as you've described, the `-replace` operation suggested in the comment should do just what you want.

All you need to do is take user input and interpolate it into the replace string, exemplified below:

```
# Get user input for the first digit
do{
    $a = Read-Host -Prompt "Input 1st digit"
} while ($a -notmatch "^\d$")

# Get user input for the third digit    
do{
    $b = Read-Host -Prompt "Input 3rd digit"
} while ($b -notmatch "^\d$")

# pattern that matches exactly 3 digits, captures the middle one
$pattern = "^\d(\d)\d$"

# replacement consisting of the user input and a reference to the capture group
$replace = "$a{0}$b" -f '${1}'

# Let's replace!
$InputObject = Get-Content "C:\my\file\path.txt"    
$InputObject -replace $pattern,$replace
```